# Can't modify little by little an image : thread is gets stuck

Tags: javafx, task

I have an image and I want to reverse it. I wrote the algorithm, it works fine.
But I want to display the reversal little by little (the pixels of the 1st column are shown, then those of the 2nd column, etc.) because it's nicer !

So I use `Service` and `Task` classes to make my class (`GraphicEngine`) which contains this algorithm a thread. The latter will be launched by another class (`Gui`), which is the GUI. It's common in JavaFX to procede like that.

The problem is that the display of the reversal gets stuck at the beginning of the image, or at the middle... it's random. I don't know why.

Here is the source-code :

**The Launcher class :**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launcher extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setWidth(700);
        stage.setHeight(700);
        stage.setMaximized(true);

        Gui gui = new Gui(stage, new BorderPane(), 700, 500);
        gui.fill();

        stage.setScene(gui);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

**In Gui.java (extends Scene) :**

```
    this.button_reverse_image.setOnAction(button -> {
        this.graphic_engine.restart();
    });
```

**In GraphicEngine.java :**

```
public class GraphicEngine extends Service<Void> {
    private WritableImage writable_image;
    private PixelReader writable_pixel_reader;
    private PixelWriter writable_pixel_writer;

    public Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {

            protected Void call() {
                double r, g, b;
                for(int x = 0; x < writable_image.getWidth(); x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < writable_image.getHeight(); y++) {
                        r = writable_pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getRed()*255;
                        g = writable_pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getGreen()*255;
                        b = writable_pixel_reader.getColor(x, y).getBlue()*255;
                        writable_pixel_writer.setColor(x, y, Color.rgb((int) (255 - r), (int) (255 - g), (int) (255 - b)));
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Do you run the task on a separate thread? Please provide the code that executes the task (presumably `GraphicEngine#restart` ? )

Comment: The `restart` is called in the class `Gui`, which extends `Scene`.

Comment: I added the source-code of the third (and last) class : the Launcher

Comment: @sillyfly `Service` manages the threads, via a default executor.

Comment: @James_D - Ah, right, I missed the fact that `GenericEngine` extends `Service`.

Comment: Well it's a very weird problem no ?

Comment: Not really: you are modifying the image from a background thread. That violates the threading rules of JavaFX.

Comment: So how I could do it ? =(

Comment: compute the matrix in the task and return it, then launch an animation in the `onSucceeded` handler, or something similar

Comment: But I won't be able to display little by little the image. My application also draws circles and these circles must be displayed exactly as they're created. So the `Task` really needs to display while creating...

Comment: "But I won't be able to display little by little the image." Why not? That's what animations do. See answer.

Comment: Moreover, the image is contained in the background task. So I think I can modify it in the background thread/task.

Comment: No, you cannot modify active UI elements on a background thread. This is explicitly stated all over the documentation, e.g. see the ["Threading" section of the `Application` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the UI from a background thread. Instead, you should use an animation (since animating the new image is effectively what you're doing).

E.g.

```
private void progressivelyWriteImage(PixelReader source, WritableImage target) {

    Duration animationDuration = Duration.seconds(1);

    int width = target.getWidth();
    int height = target.getHeight();

    PixelWriter pixelWriter = target.getPixelWriter();

    IntegerProperty columnProgression = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    columnProgression.addListener((obs, oldX, newX) -> {
        int progWidth = newX.intValue() - oldX.intValue();
        int[] pixels = new int[progWidth*height];
        source.getPixels(oldX.intValue(), 0, progWidth, height,
            PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
            pixels, 0, progWidth);
        int[] newPixels = new int[pixels.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length ; i++) {
            int a = pixels[i] & 0xFF000000 ;
            int rgb = 0xFFFFFF - (pixels[i] & 0xFFFFFF) ;
            newPixels[i] = a | rgb ;
        }
        pixelWriter.setPixels(oldX.intValue(), 0, progWidth, height,
            PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
            newPixels, 0, progWidth);
    });

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(animationDuration,
        new KeyValue(columnProgression, width)));
    timeline.play();
}
```

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class GraphicEngine() {

    public negateImage(PixelReader source, WritableImage target) {

        Duration animationDuration = Duration.seconds(1);

        int width = (int) target.getWidth();
        int height = (int) target.getHeight();

        PixelWriter pixelWriter = target.getPixelWriter();

        IntegerProperty columnProgression = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        columnProgression.addListener((obs, oldX, newX) -> {
            int progWidth = newX.intValue() - oldX.intValue();
            int[] pixels = new int[progWidth*height];
            source.getPixels(oldX.intValue(), 0, progWidth, height,
                PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
                pixels, 0, progWidth);
            int[] newPixels = new int[pixels.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length ; i++) {
                int a = pixels[i] & 0xFF000000 ;
                int rgb = 0xFFFFFF - (pixels[i] & 0xFFFFFF) ;
                newPixels[i] = a | rgb ;
            }
            pixelWriter.setPixels(oldX.intValue(), 0, progWidth, height,
                PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
                newPixels, 0, progWidth);
        });

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(animationDuration,
            new KeyValue(columnProgression, width)));
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelFormat;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ImageModifyDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GraphicEngine engine = new GraphicEngine();
        Image initialImage = createImage();

        int width = (int) initialImage.getWidth();
        int height = (int) initialImage.getHeight();
        WritableImage target = new WritableImage(width, height);

        Button demoChange = new Button("Run demo");
        demoChange.setOnAction(e -> {
            target.getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), new int[width], 0, 0);
            engine.negateImage(initialImage.getPixelReader(), target);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, new ImageView(initialImage), new ImageView(target), demoChange);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private Image createImage() {
        Label label = new Label("Hello world");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: -fx-background; -fx-background: salmon; -fx-font-size:72;");
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem here is that I really have to write the algorithm in a class "A", and to do the display in another class "B". I have to separate them in fact. In your last solution, `progressivelyWriteImage` modifies and display the modification. Is it impossible to store the animation in `ImageUpdate`, for example ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what class the method is in. What matters is that you do the UI update on the FX application thread. Move the `progressivelyWriteIage` method to a new class if you prefer to organise your code that way.

Comment: Can I keep my GraphicEngine, which extends Service and my Task (you use a Thread instead) ? And can I put the line `int[] newPixels = new int[height] ;` before the first for (I will have to change it to : `new int[height*width]`) ?

Comment: In fact I think I don't need an int[] buffer, because I want to draw my image pixel by pixel (not column by column), does it simplify your code ?

Comment: The `Service` class runs the `Task`s it creates in a background thread. Again (for the third time or so) *you must not modify the UI from a background thread*. So you can use another class, but **do not use a `Service`**. There is no reason at all to use background threads for this: you should use an animation to do what you want. Sure, if you are updating one pixel at a time, then use an `int` instead of an `int[]`: but these details are nothing to do with the problem you are seeing, which (as far as I can tell) is caused by updating the UI from a background thread.

Comment: Okay :) Thank you very much. I adapted your code to use a single pixel (I created a class Pixel with 3 attributes : x, y, and Color) and it works fine ! Well, I must learn how your code works (I began JavaFX few days ago, and I don't know how Animations work), especially why a Concurrent Array (BlockingArrayQueue) is needed. But thank you very much :) !

Comment: The `BlockingQueue` is only needed in the version that uses a background thread, but I really don't think you need that. Did you try the simpler version with the `Timeline`?

Comment: Yes I need it so indeed I must use this version (not the `Timeline` one). I have removed the class `ImageUpdate` and change the `BlockingQueue<ImageUpdate>` to a `BlockingQueue<Pixel>` , it works fine (now the GUI displays the pixel). I have a question : can I replace this `BlockingQueue` directly with a `Pixel` ? I'm not sure I really need a `Collection`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get why this has to be done in a different thread. What on earth is the point of that? I'm actually going to remove that from the answer as it is just going to be too misleading to anyone else with a similar issue who comes across this question.

Comment: And, if for some bizarre reason you really do want to create an unnecessary thread, you do need to collect the updates. The background thread might (probably will) create multiple updates before the animation timer has a chance to process them.